# This.localStream is null

Tags: chat, videocall, connectycube

I'm trying to develop and application that allow to a medic and a patient be able to communicate using an Api called connectycube, the chat and video call work, the problem is with to mute sound and video. I have implemented the buttons to mute sound and video, all this using jQuery dialogs, the first time I mute audio or video works, but when I close the dialog finishing the session and then I open the dialog with a new session, to mute audio and video do not work anymore and the message in the console is **This.localStream is null**

My Source Code:

```
const CREDENTIALS = {
            appId: 'xxxxx',
            authKey: 'xxxxx',
            authSecret: 'xxxxx'
        };
        
        ConnectyCube.init(CREDENTIALS);
        
                //This is a button in a main jquery dialog, this is the beginning of all
                {
                    text: 'VideoCall',
                    click: function () {
                        $('#dv_progess').html('<div class="dv_progress">Connecting</div>').dialog('open');
                        ConnectyCube.createSession().then((session) => {
                            $('#dv_progess').dialog('close');
                            signup_user();
                            $('#dv_videocall').dialog('option', 'position', {my: 'right top', at: 'right top', of: window}).dialog('open');
                        }).catch((error) => {
                            console.log('Error=>' + JSON.stringify(error));
                            $('#dv_progess').dialog('close');
                            $('#dv_message').html('Error=>' + JSON.stringify(error)).dialog('open');
                        });
                    }
                },


        function signup_user() {
            var login = 'P' + $('#hd_idusr').val();
            /*Buscar si existe usuario registrado en la API*/
            $('#dv_progress').html('<div class="dv_progress">Connecting</div>').dialog('open');
            ConnectyCube.users.get({login: login}).then((result) => {
                console.log('User Exists:' + result.user.id);
                $('#dv_progress').dialog('close');
                chat();
            }).catch((error) => {
                $('#dv_progress').dialog('close');
                console.log('User not exists [' + error.info.message + ']');
                var password = $('#txt_birthdate').val().replace(/-/g, '') + '*';
                var email = $('#hd_email').val();
                email = email ? email : login + '@email.com';

                const userProfile = {
                    login: login,
                    password: password,
                    full_name: $('#txt_names').val(),
                    email: email
                };

                $('#dv_progress').html('<div class="dv_progress">Connecting</div>').dialog('open');
                ConnectyCube.users.signup(userProfile).then((data) => {
                    console.log('ok=>' + data.user.id);
                    $('#dv_progress').dialog('close');
                    chat();
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log('Error=>' + JSON.stringify(error));
                    $('#dv_progress').dialog('close');
                    $('#dv_messages').html('Error=>' + JSON.stringify(error)).dialog('open');
                });
            });
        }

        function chat() {
            $('#dv_progress').html('<div class="dv_progress">Connecting</div>').dialog('open');
            var login_patient = 'P' + $('#hd_idusr').val();
            ConnectyCube.users.get({login: login_patient}).then((result) => {
                $('#dv_progress').dialog('close');
                var id_patient = result.user.id;
                $('#hd_idpatient').val(id_patient);
                
                const userCredentials = {
                    login: 'S' + $('#txt_medic').attr('data-id-user'),
                    password: $('#txt_medic').attr('data-psw')
                };
                $('#dv_progress').html('<div class="dv_progress">Connecting</div>').dialog('open');
                ConnectyCube.createSession(userCredentials).then((session) => {
                    $('#dv_progress').dialog('close');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(session));
                    console.log('Medic Created session');

                    $('#dv_progress').html('<div class="dv_progress">Connecting</div>').dialog('open');
                    ConnectyCube.login(userCredentials).then((user) => {
                        var id_professional = user.id;
                        console.log('Medic login succesful=>' + id_professional);
                        $('#hd_idprofessional').val(id_professional);
                        const chatCredentials = {
                            userId: id_professional,
                            password: $('#txt_medic').attr('data-psw')
                        };

                        $('#dv_progress').html('<div class="dv_progress">Connecting</div>').dialog('open');
                        ConnectyCube.chat.connect(chatCredentials).then(() => {
                            $('#dv_progress').dialog('close');
                            console.log('Medic Connected to chat');
                            console.log('Id Paciente:' + id_patient);

                            const dialogParams = {
                                type: 3,
                                occupants_ids: [id_patient]
                            };

                            $('#dv_progress').html('<div class="dv_progress">Connecting</div>').dialog('open');
                            ConnectyCube.chat.dialog.create(dialogParams).then(dialog => {
                                $('#dv_progress').dialog('close');
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(dialog));
                                console.log('Dialog Created:' + dialog._id);
                                $('#hd_iddialog').val(dialog._id);
                                $('#dv_messagearea').prop('contenteditable', true);
                                $('#btn_sendmsg,#btn_startvideocall,#btn_finishvideocall').prop('disabled', false);
                            }).catch(error => {
                                console.log('Error=>' + JSON.stringify(error));
                                $('#dv_progress').dialog('close');
                                $('#dv_messages').html('Error=>' + JSON.stringify(error)).dialog('open');
                            });
                        }).catch((error) => {
                            console.log('Error:' + JSON.stringify(error));
                            $('#dv_progress').dialog('close');
                            $('#dv_messages').html('Error:' + JSON.stringify(error)).dialog('open');
                        });

                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log('Error:' + JSON.stringify(error));
                        $('#dv_progress').dialog('close');
                        $('#dv_messages').html('Error:' + JSON.stringify(error)).dialog('open');
                    });

                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log('Error=>' + JSON.stringify(error));
                    $('#dv_progress').dialog('close');
                    $('#dv_messages').html('Error=>' + JSON.stringify(error)).dialog('open');
                });
                /*Fin Login Medico*/
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error=>' + JSON.stringify(error));
                $('#dv_progress').dialog('close');
                $('#dv_messages').html('Error=>' + JSON.stringify(error)).dialog('open');
            });
        }

        function onMessage(userId, message) {
            console.log('[ConnectyCube.chat.onMessageListener] callback:', userId, message);
            var dv_message = $('#dv_messageschat');
            dv_message.append('<div><b>Patient:</b>' + message.body + '</div>');
            dv_message.scrollTop(dv_message[0].scrollHeight);
        }

        function isTyPing(isTyping, userId, dialogId) {
            console.log("[ConnectyCube.chat.onMessageTypingListener] callback:", isTyping, userId, dialogId);
        }

        function sendMessage() {
            ConnectyCube.chat.sendIsStopTypingStatus($('#hd_idpatient').val());
            var mensaje = $('#dv_messagearea').text();
            const message = {
                type: 'chat',
                body: mensaje,
                extension: {
                    save_to_history: 1,
                    dialog_id: $('#hd_iddialog').val()
                },
                markable: 1
            };
            message.id = ConnectyCube.chat.send($('#hd_idpatient').val(), message);
            var dv_message = $('#dv_messageschat');
            dv_message.append('<div><b>Yo:</b>' + mensaje + '</div>');
            dv_message.scrollTop(dv_message[0].scrollHeight);
            $('#dv_messagearea').html('');
        }

        $('#dv_messagearea').keypress(function (e) {
            ConnectyCube.chat.sendIsTypingStatus($('#hd_idpatient').val());
            setTimeout(function () {
                ConnectyCube.chat.sendIsStopTypingStatus($('#hd_idpatient').val());
            }, 1000);
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                sendMessage();
                return false;
            }
        });

        function startVideo() {
            const calleesIds = [$('#hd_idprofessional').val(), $('#hd_idpatient').val()]; /*User's ids*/
            const sessionType = ConnectyCube.videochat.CallType.VIDEO;
            const additionalOptions = {};
            const session = ConnectyCube.videochat.createNewSession(calleesIds, sessionType, additionalOptions);
            
            const mediaParams = {
                audio: true,
                video: true,
                options: {
                    muted: true,
                    mirror: true
                }
            };

            session.getUserMedia(mediaParams).then((localStream) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(localStream));
                session.attachMediaStream('vd_video1', localStream);
                /*Iniciar la llamada*/
                const extension = {};
                session.call(extension, (error) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                });
                $('#btn_finishvideocall').on('click', {x: session}, finishCall);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        }

        function finishCall(e) {
            const extension = {};
            e.data.x.stop(extension);
            /*Clean local stream*/
            var videoElem1 = document.getElementById('vd_video1'),
                    stream1 = videoElem1.srcObject;
            if (stream1 != null) {
                var tracks = stream1.getTracks();
                tracks.forEach(function (track) {
                    track.stop();
                });
                videoElem1.srcObject = null;
            }

            /*Clean remote stream*/
            var videoElem2 = document.getElementById('vd_video2'),
                    stream2 = videoElem2.srcObject;
            if (stream2 != null) {
                var tracks = stream2.getTracks();
                tracks.forEach(function (track) {
                    track.stop();
                });
                videoElem2.srcObject = null;
            }
        }

        $('#dv_controllsvideocall').find('button').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#btn_mutesound,#btn_mutevideo').hide();

        function setSound(e) {
            const session = e.data.x;
            if (e.data.y == 'mute') {
                $('#btn_mutesound').show();
                $('#btn_unmutesound').hide();
                session.mute('audio');
                console.log('muted audio');
            } else {
                $('#btn_mutesound').hide();
                $('#btn_unmutesound').show();
                session.unmute('audio');
                console.log('unmuted audio');
            }
        }

        function setVideo(e) {
            const session = e.data.x;
            if (e.data.y == 'mute') {
                $('#btn_mutevideo').show();
                $('#btn_unmutevideo').hide();
                session.mute('video');
                console.log('muted video');
            } else {
                $('#btn_mutevideo').hide();
                $('#btn_unmutevideo').show();
                session.unmute('video');
                console.log('unmuted video');
            }
        }

        function acceptedCall(session, userId, extension) {
            console.log('Accepted call');
            $('#dv_controllsvideocall').find('button').prop('disabled', false);
        }

        function setStream(session, userID, remoteStream) {
            console.log('stream assigned');
            session.attachMediaStream('vd_video2', remoteStream);
            $('#btn_mutesound').on('click', {x: session, y: 'unmute'}, setSound);
            $('#btn_unmutesound').on('click', {x: session, y: 'mute'}, setSound);
            $('#btn_mutevideo').on('click', {x: session, y: 'unmute'}, setVideo);
            $('#btn_unmutevideo').on('click', {x: session, y: 'mute'}, setVideo);
        }

        function onStopCall(session, userId, extension) {
            console.log('Finished Call');
        }

        ConnectyCube.chat.onMessageListener = onMessage;
        ConnectyCube.chat.onMessageTypingListener = isTyPing;
        ConnectyCube.videochat.onAcceptCallListener = acceptedCall;
        ConnectyCube.videochat.onRemoteStreamListener = setStream;
        ConnectyCube.videochat.onStopCallListener = onStopCall;

        $('#btn_sendmsg').click(function () {
            sendMessage();
        });

        $('#btn_startvideocall').click(function () {
            startVideo();
        });

        $('#btn_exitvideocall').click(function () {
            $('#dv_videocall').dialog('close');
        });

        /*Dialog for video call*/
        $('#dv_videocall').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 220,
            modal: false,
            close: function () {
                $(this).find('input').val('');
                $('#dv_messagearea').prop('contenteditable', false).html('');
                $('#dv_messageschat').html('');
                $('#btn_sendmsg,#btn_startvideocall,#btn_finishvideocall').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#dv_controllsvideocall').find('button').prop('disabled', true);

                if (ConnectyCube.chat.isConnected) {
                    $('#btn_finishvideocall').trigger('click');
                    ConnectyCube.chat.disconnect();
                    ConnectyCube.logout().catch((error) => {
                        console.log('logout=>' + JSON.stringify(error));
                    });
                    ConnectyCube.destroySession().catch((error) => {
                        console.log('destroySession=>' + JSON.stringify(error));
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
            if (ConnectyCube.chat.isConnected) {
                $('#btn_finishvideocall').trigger('click');
                ConnectyCube.chat.disconnect();
                ConnectyCube.logout().catch((error) => {
                    console.log('logout=>' + JSON.stringify(error));
                });
                ConnectyCube.destroySession().catch((error) => {
                    console.log('destroySession=>' + JSON.stringify(error));
                });
            }
        });
```

[image]

I think the problem is in the function **finishCall()** when I clean the video tag and I don't know if that is the right way to free the resources. Despite this the chat and video call still work.

If someone has experience please help me, becasue I didn't found any solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: please share html page too.

Comment: pls share it in jsfiddle

Comment: Since ConnectyCube is Premium service try Approaching them

Comment: so we suppose to try to reverse engineer the html?

Comment: https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-web-samples/issues/72